# Why is electric potential function in free space infinitely differentiable?

Tags: derivatives, continuity, infinity, potential-theory, electromagnetism

Electric potential function in free space of a continuous charge distribution $\rho'$ distributed over volume $V' \subset \mathbb{R}^3$ is denoted by:

$\psi (x,y,z): \mathbb{R}^3 \setminus{V'} \to \mathbb{R}$

and is defined as:

$$\psi (x,y,z)=\int_{V'} \dfrac{\rho'}{R}\ dV'$$

where $R$ is distance between point $(x,y,z)$ to a point $ P \in V'$

I know electric potential function in free space is *differentiable once* but I don't see why it is *infinitely differentiable*. Please explain why it is so.

> **EDIT**
>
> **Theorem:** PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of all orders are differentiable in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus (R=0)$
>
> **Proof:**
>
> Let $P_k$ denote polynomials of degree $k$ in $x,y,z,x',y',z'$
>
> $$\dfrac{\partial\frac{1}{R}}{\partial x}=-\dfrac{x-x'}{R^3};\
> \dfrac{\partial\frac{1}{R}}{\partial y}=-\dfrac{y-y'}{R^3};\
> \dfrac{\partial\frac{1}{R}}{\partial z}=-\dfrac{z-z'}{R^3}$$
>
> Therefore:
>
> PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of $1^{st}$ order = $\dfrac{P_1}{R^{(2 \times 1) + 1}}$
>
> \begin{align}
> \text{PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of $k^{th}$ order} &= \dfrac{P_k}{R^{2k + 1}}\\
> \implies \text{PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of $(k+1)^{th}$ order} &= \dfrac{\partial}{\partial x} [\text{PD of $k^{th}$ order} ]\\
> &= \dfrac{\partial \left[    \dfrac{P_k}{R^{2k + 1}}    \right]}{\partial x}\\
> &= \dfrac{(P_k)'_x}{R^{2k+1}} - (2k+1) \dfrac{P_k}{R^{2k+2}} \dfrac{x-x'}{R}\\
> &= \dfrac{(P_k)'_x\ [(x-x')^2+(y-y')^2+(z-z')^2]}{R^{2k+3}} - \dfrac{(2k+1)\ P_k\ (x-x')}{R^{2k+3}}\\
> &=\dfrac{P_{k+1}}{R^{2(k+1)+1}}\\
> \end{align}
>
> Thus by induction:
>
> PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of $n^{th}$ order $=\dfrac{P_k}{R^{2n+1}}$
>
> $P_k$, being a polynomial function is continuous in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3}$
>
> $\dfrac{1}{R^{2n+1}}$, being a radial function is continuous in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus (R=0)$
>
> Thus:
>
> PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of $n^{th}$ order is continuous in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus (R=0)$
>
> PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of all orders are continuous in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus (R=0)$
>
> PD of $\dfrac{1}{R}$ of all orders are differentiable in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus (R=0)$

**Now how shall we prove PD if $\psi$ of all orders are differentiable in $x,y,z$ in domain $\mathbb{R^3} \setminus {V'}$?**

Comment: After how many derivatives does $1/R$ stop being differentiable?

Comment: Shall I check it by brute force or is there a shortcut?

Comment: In domain $\mathbb{R}^3 \setminus (R=0)$, $1/R$ is differentiable as its partial derivatives w.r.t $x,y,z$ exists and they are continuous. I can go on and check similarly for the next three PD of first order. Then for the next nine PD of second order...... and so on. There must be a shortcut to figure out the infinite differentiability of $1/R$ in one or two steps. Sorry I do not know that shortcut. Please mention if such a shortcut exists.

Comment: $1/R$ is a spherically symmetric function. Therefore so is its derivative. Same reasoning applied the derivative says the second derivative is spherically symmetric, and so forth ad infinitum. So you only need to look at what happens on one radial, for example the positive $x$ axis.

Comment: I get your point. But here we have to take the derivative of $1/R$ w.r.t. $x,y,z$ and not w.r.t. $R$. How can the reasoning you gave in the comment be extended to the case of the derivative of $1/R$ w.r.t. $x,y,z$

Comment: When I wrote "look at what happens on the positive $x$ axis", I meant take the derivative of $1/R$ wrt $x,y,z.$ The $y$ and $z$ parts are trivial but no less valid for that.

Comment: @DavidK: Please look at the theorem in edit.

Comment: Can you show that the square root function is infinitely differentiable in its domain?  Can you show that the reciprocal of an infinitely differentiable function is infinitely differentiable also?  Can you show that the composite of infinitely differentiable functions is infinitely differentiable also?

Comment: Aside, the function $1/R$ may be written in terms of series of infinitely differentiable basis functions.

Comment: Finally, you have shown that $\partial_i^k(R^{-1}) =P_{ik}/R^{2k+1}$.  And that suffices.